# Regular expression for IPV4 address validation

Tags: c#, regex

I need a small help in creating a regular expression for IPV4 address validation.
My validation string is as below..

> http?s://IP:port/

What I have tried is given below...

```
private bool IsUrlValid(string url)
  {
    Regex urlRx = new Regex(@"^https?://(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 return urlRx.IsMatch(url);
  }
```

With this code, I could perfectly validate an IPV4 address without port; But I want to modify this to accept port number also. 
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Sebastian

Comment: http://dashasalo.com/2011/02/10/regular-expression-for-url-ip-with-port-number/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very good idea to do it with regex. The port has range 1~65535. So we can validate it against `6553[0-5]`, `655[0-2]\d`, `65[0-4]\d{2}`, `6[0-4]\d{3}`, `[1-5]\d{4}`, `[1-9]\d{,3}`. It would give for string containing only port the following regex:

```
^(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3})$
```

Combining with your IP address pattern:

```
^https?://(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3})/$
```

If port is optional:

```
^https?://(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(:(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}))?/$
```

Comment: This is good solution, but in this case we need to input port; in my case, port # is not mandatory. Please check the below expression, I have added a ? just before your addition.

^https?://(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):?(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3})/$

Thanks for your help

Comment: @user1805353 You have to wrap `:port` into optional group like `(:port)?`. I updated the answer.